# Modal CSS height 100% doesn't cover screen after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

Taking an intro web design class so my knowledge is very limited. I'm working on a page that is supposed to display modals after clicking on an image. It seems to be working fine except for when they scroll down first then click the modal. When that happens the modal is cut off and doesn't display in the whole page. After some searching, I know Height 100% doesn't work if the user scrolls so is there any way to solve that? Here is my code, apologies if it's not written well, modals haven't been taught in class yet so I had watch some videos on youtube to make this.

Comment: It is correct and working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/bortao/3L18kjv0/

Comment: you can declare multiple classes with same style using ".close1, .close2, .close3"... you can also use the same class on multiple elements

Comment: wow i swear it didn't work when i was testing earlier, must have forgotten to refresh after testing different ways to do it .-.

Comment: if you dont mind I have another question, when you scroll down and click on the image, the "transparent" part doesn't quite seem to cover the entire page. Is there a way to fix that? Stopping the scroll was an attempt to do that but it seems like it wont work if they scroll down before clicking an image..

Comment: There's a ton of superfluous code there. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the main model wrapper `position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%;` and for stopping the scrolling makes body `overflow: hidden;` as you already did. After close the modal make the body overflow: auto/scroll.

For better understanding use this guideline [ similar to bootstrap 4 ]

```js
document.getElementById('modal-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('active');
  document.body.classList.add('modal-has-opened');
});

document.getElementById('modal-hide').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.remove('active');
  document.body.classList.remove('modal-has-opened');
})
```

```css
.modal{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  display: none;
}
.modal.active{
  display: block;
}

.modal-content{
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

body{
  background-color: #f4f8ff;
    font-family: segoe ui;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.wp{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#modal-btn{
  padding: .25rem 1.25rem;
  font-family: segoe ui;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}


@media(max-width: 442px){
  .modal-content{
    width: 98%;
  }
}


.modal-has-opened{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 17px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wp">
  <div class="title">
  I am fine
</div>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ipsa hic recusandae dolor. Cumque, ea. Fugiat ratione laudantium blanditiis dolore expedita? Adipisci inventore saepe minus quisquam natus officiis enim! Quia in explicabo aliquid illo voluptate nam laboriosam ad minus voluptas, repellendus provident. Temporibus voluptatum ut quia cum possimus inventore ratione?</p>
  
  <button id="modal-btn">
    Open Modal
  </button>
</div>

<div class="wp">
  <div class="title">
  I am fine
</div>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ipsa hic recusandae dolor. Cumque, ea. Fugiat ratione laudantium blanditiis dolore expedita? Adipisci inventore saepe minus quisquam natus officiis enim! Quia in explicabo aliquid illo voluptate nam laboriosam ad minus voluptas, repellendus provident. Temporibus voluptatum ut quia cum possimus inventore ratione?</p>

</div>


<!-- Main Modal -->

<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal-content">
      I am the content
       <button id="modal-hide">
    Close Modal
  </button>
     
     <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, fugit quo? Illo saepe magni molestias, accusantium molestiae, similique quibusdam officia fuga id adipisci suscipit architecto, omnis quo cum labore fugiat. Facere vel nulla blanditiis, voluptatem animi debitis, asperiores alias error sed tempora cum, architecto quia cumque distinctio sit ab nemo minima eveniet esse possimus deleniti omnis? Modi unde repellat quasi reiciendis suscipit corporis explicabo! Quaerat eveniet, ad iusto commodi officia ea quae dolor, quia architecto quibusdam voluptate autem vero. Eaque quasi temporibus recusandae. Quasi assumenda vero in odio sit neque modi deleniti quaerat laborum. Reiciendis dicta sunt laborum assumenda aliquid cumque sint recusandae temporibus itaque nisi, velit magnam officia inventore, id laboriosam! Aliquam expedita voluptate vel neque aspernatur obcaecati minus, tempora laudantium illum, eveniet totam eum incidunt. Quo consectetur dolorum, aliquid quas dicta quasi nisi soluta eaque earum nostrum exercitationem possimus tempore quisquam distinctio ducimus deleniti modi consequatur quod obcaecati maxime rem. Totam quos nisi natus laudantium nobis culpa fugit aspernatur quis voluptatum consequuntur perferendis incidunt fugiat alias quaerat architecto deserunt at, consequatur dolorum sequi sed, fuga quia! Officia dignissimos non id quam quibusdam ipsam cupiditate laborum blanditiis placeat minus cumque, harum expedita accusantium eligendi quo similique debitis fugiat eius natus? Placeat quis consectetur hic natus quam veritatis earum ipsam minima dolorem molestiae nemo fuga exercitationem vero repudiandae facere delectus autem iste at saepe sapiente, veniam doloremque! Error dolor dolorem cupiditate ab qui doloribus sapiente, cum eaque consectetur debitis aliquid maiores perspiciatis dignissimos officia ea possimus molestias? Earum rerum reiciendis possimus amet, voluptas qui minima velit veniam at consequuntur optio iusto repellat eveniet placeat autem ea, ipsam sunt ab commodi quos maiores. Ad a voluptatem quasi in molestiae expedita dolorem rerum eius id dignissimos neque sunt officia magnam et repellat suscipit, soluta fuga temporibus porro ab omnis nesciunt! Deleniti itaque quae, accusamus reprehenderit minus repellendus cupiditate nihil earum in, dolorem illum nobis excepturi velit ipsam modi dolores praesentium? Necessitatibus doloribus animi aut quos provident iusto reiciendis, asperiores corrupti voluptatem ipsa veniam libero ullam illo iure rem harum laborum porro at, neque, cum maxime tempora? Deleniti cupiditate omnis nesciunt error asperiores delectus quo architecto dolorem ut nostrum. Dolorem blanditiis quos est delectus quo soluta illo officiis, eum rem ad minus corporis optio minima cumque voluptates maiores ipsa quas! At numquam tempora explicabo soluta. Natus perferendis cumque fuga iusto nostrum porro nihil exercitationem incidunt suscipit voluptatum vero, rem molestias, commodi sit, corporis animi aliquid aperiam quam. Blanditiis, minima necessitatibus. Maxime, optio officiis quia commodi consectetur dignissimos omnis accusantium, nesciunt reiciendis illum voluptates id aspernatur officia suscipit, numquam earum recusandae voluptas voluptate eum illo nemo. Ea ipsam laboriosam similique veniam nesciunt labore esse laborum nulla. Laboriosam pariatur ex ipsa assumenda ad soluta alias, explicabo id accusamus nulla non reprehenderit perspiciatis quas nisi. Unde ad voluptatem quis, quo repellendus odit sint tempore non ex, similique architecto dolor. Eius quaerat enim accusamus nobis animi dignissimos earum eaque atque culpa optio esse iusto iure adipisci, deleniti qui voluptate. Dolor velit possimus placeat a quidem commodi quod?
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```